# Selenium: Don't understand how to write correct xpath for IMDB top movies

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to click on the IMDB Top Rated Movies which is under "Movies, TV & Showtimes" but I don't understand how to write the correct and precise xpath for it. I am not able to click on the Top Rated Movies part.

Below is the code:

```
driver.get("http://www.imdb.com");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("navTitleMenu"))).build().perform();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='navTitleMenu']/div/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/a")).click();
```

Help me out. Thanks already.

Comment: so where are you clicking using this xpath? or are you getting any error or exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what worked in my case:

```
    driver.get("http://www.imdb.com");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("navTitleMenu")));
    new Actions(driver)
            .clickAndHold(driver.findElement(By.id("navTitleMenu")))
            .moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Top Rated Movies")))
            .click()
            .build().perform();
```

The problem is that when you move to `navTitleMenu` - you should continue performing your actions, as focus will be lost from dropdown (so it will be closed)

Answer (score 1):

do you create the xpath yourself i recommend using chrome to create the xpath maybe the problem is that your xpath is incorrect try this:

```
//*[@id="navMenu1"]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/a
```

or if not maybe you should wait a little to get the page load done try

```
try {
        // thread to sleep for 5 seconds
        Thread.sleep(5000);
     } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
     }
```

then

```
driver
.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id="navMenu1"]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/a")).click();
```

Comment: So basically the problem was with not giving it enough time to load. I thought it wouldn't be a problem as mouse hover was working properly. But I guess this was it. 
Thank You.

Comment: please add reputation so other people with problem like yours can solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

First of all,
Forget about the implicit wait, It is not needed since IMDB is a stable site

Add explicit wait after you have performed the mousehover. It will definitely work for you.

Try the exact code mentioned below, Working fine with my browser.

Please change the gecko driver path according to location in your directory

```
     package com.imdb.top;

     import org.openqa.selenium.By;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
     import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
     import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;



     public class Imdb
     {
     public static void main(String...  args)
     {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
    "C:\\Users\\thinksysuser\\Downloads\
    \geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

     driver.get("http://www.imdb.com");



     Actions action = new Actions(driver);




     action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("navTitleMenu")))
                 .build().perform();

     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60, 50);

     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*
     [@id='navMenu1']/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/a"))).click();

     driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*
     [@id='navMenu1']/div[2]/ul[1]/li[6]/a")).click();
    }
 }
```